# How to find the edit link of the WordPress Post from the URL

Tags: posts

I have a url /abcde-post and it is redirecting to home page. Is there a way in wordpress to find out the post edit link from the url

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can use [`url_to_postid`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid) function:

```
$postid = url_to_postid( $url );
```

It will give you ID of a post based on URL.

So if you want to get edit link, then this will do exactly that:

```
$postid = url_to_postid( $url );
if ( $postid ) {
    echo get_edit_post_link( $postid );
}
```